# Using CSS ::after without inheriting parent tag

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to achieve the following display and would like to know if there are cleaner ways to code it (eg. ::after). Note that the header is suppose to be underline but the "." is not part of the underline. An alternative to do it is to have 2 span class which i am trying to avoid.

> Heading One.       This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.
>
> Heading Two.      This is also a para. This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.This is also a para.

My codes are as follows:

```
     <STYLE>
     .headingTitle{
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:underline;
        padding-right: 1em;
     }

     .headingTitle::after{
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        content:".";
     }
     </STYLE>

     <li><span class="headingTitle">Heading One</span>This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.</li>
```

Comment: You have a typo. Use `.headingTitle` and your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/2psvhrkk/

Comment: @JonP The OP's problem is that they don't want to underline the period.

Comment: Ahh, well! There is still the typo issue.

Comment: OP - are you open to utilizing JS?

Comment: @JonP thanks for highlighting my typo which i have corrected in my question above. but like the reply of Mr Lister, i'm trying to remove the underline from the period. Thanks.

Comment: @LloanAlas you can suggest, but at the same time, i am trying to avoid. but do share so that others who face similar issue can take as reference.

Comment: @CBroe how would you suggest i change my title?

Comment: One way to suppress the underline is to give it a colour that is the same as the background colour. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2psvhrkk/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** I've take the CSS3 out. `inline-block` seems sufficeint.

Taken from info at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration. Also note that this doesn't work in IE. I've successfully tested in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
.headingTitle{
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:underline;
        padding-right: 1em;
        display:inline-block;
     }

     .headingTitle::after{
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        content:".";
        display:inline-block;
     }
```

```html
<ul>

  <li><span class="headingTitle">Heading One</span>This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.This is a para.</li>
</ul>
```

I wish I knew why this works!

Comment: The first paragraph of https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration explains it somehow I guess. Not sure which of those conditions exactly applies here, but it has something to do with the inline boxes.

Comment: @jon P Mine works after removing the display:inline-block from the main class and declaring it in the ::after. Somehow it only worked that way.  Thanks for the solutions :)